# Checking if a table has been created not working

Tags: lua, love2d

Using the code:

```
function createNewBody(name,mass)
if not world.body[name]==nil then
    print("This body has already been created. Maybe you meant to update it's values?\n")
else
    world.body[name]={mass=m,x=0,y=0,xAccel=0,yAccel=0,xR=0,yR=0,properties={gaseous=false,texture=""}}
    world.bodies=world.bodies+1
end
end
```

This code shows no errors, but when I bind createNewBody(moon,1.622) to a key and then use it, it lets me spam the key without showing the error message.

And, yes, I have defined `world.bodies` and `world.body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`not world.body[name]==nil` is parsed as `(not world.body[name])==nil`. Since the result of `not` is a boolean, it is never `nil`.

Try `not(world.body[name]==nil)` or `world.body[name]~=nil`.

Comment: So, I have simplified my code and it still does not work. D: Take a look. @lhf https://gyazo.com/b54e16a8652ad22bd5f3a012c2635534 The first time pressing the button tells me It has been created already.

Comment: Or ```if world.body[name]``` and completely forget comparing it to nil.

Comment: @warspyking Very smart suggestion! Thanks! :)

Comment: `if world.body[name]` is not exactly the same thing because `iworld.body[name]` might contain `false`.